# Eclipse E4 - IEclipseContext usability

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rcp, e4

Hello I'm using (in the Core Expressions) an IEclipseContext object in order to store a String thru its .set method.

```
IEclipseContext mycontext;
mycontext.set("mystring","com.test.test2");
```

By the way its scope is limited to the class/part where it's declared.
Is there any alternative Eclipse API that could be shared among classes and accepted by Core Expressions as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple contexts arranged in a tree structure, one leaf of the tree will be the context for the current part, the top of the tree is the application context.

When objects are looked up the tree is searched from the current leaf up to the top of the tree.

So if you place your object in the application level context it can be found anywhere.

The simplest way to get the application context is:

```
@Inject
MApplication application;

...

IEclipseContext appContext = application.getContext();
```

Comment: Thanks greg! Where can I define an object at the application level considering that i'm using the e4 schema? LifeCycle would aim to that purpose?

Comment: The @PostContextCreate in the LifeCycle would be a good place. The IEclipseContext injected there is the application context.

Answer (score 0):

Greg it works thanks! Here it's:

```
@Inject
MApplication application;

...

IEclipseContext appContext = application.getContext();                      
appContext.set(ID, Value);
```

Then if you need that value back:

```
appContext.get(ID);
```